# I want to enter images in my android activity. Where should I put the images?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-imageview, android-image

I'm using Android Studio 1.2.2 I made a form activity and I want to insert an image. Where should I put the image? What changes I have to do in my `mainactivity.java` 
 file?

Comment: First, add the images to the res/drawable folder of your project. Then place ImageViews in your layout .xml file, and add the src of the ImageView as the drawable image. The src would be something like 'android:src="@drawable/my_image"'

Comment: did you created the form view in form activity dynamically or just inflated it from the xml file? If you used layout xml file then why don't you add image using ImageView...If you create dynamically then create ImageView dynamically and add it in the parent view. And make sure you have images in res folders accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Android's ImageView tag. You need to write it inside .xml file of your activity. You can take reference of it from android's devloper's website.

In Andorid studio you can not directly drag & drop images.

It will be good for you to take reference of any example.Here is the ImageView xml code.

```
 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/android" />
```

You can now make this ImageView reference in your MainActivity (Java) like below:

ImageView imageView;
imageView  = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the docs: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html

Commonly, you will want to use some of the qualifiers by screen density and provide each image at different resolutions, docs [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html), this way lets Android pick up the best image size and scale it to match the phone screen.

Personally i use -nodpi and perform scalation by code, this way lets only have one copy of each image, and, gives you max control to position and size your images.

Hope this helps.